# Web3.js error "unknown account" when I call mint function

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm trying to call a mint function from js using web3.js and I get unknown account.

this is my smart contract function

```
function assign(string calldata tokenURI, bytes calldata bytesId) public {
    uint256 _tokenId = abi.decode(bytesId, (uint256));
    _mint(msg.sender, _tokenId);
    _setTokenURI(_tokenId, tokenURI);
    emit Assigned(_tokenId, msg.sender, bytesId);
}
```

This is my js code

```
  Contract.setProvider("https://rpc.ankr.com/polygon_mumbai");
  const contract = new Contract(CONTRACT_NFT_ABI, CONTRACT_NFT_ADDRESS);

  await contract.methods.assign(tokenURI, plotID)
  .send({from: userAddress}, function(error, transactionHash){
    if (transactionHash){
      res.status(200).send({
        res: "OK",
        msg: transactionHash
      });              
    }
    if (error) {
      res.status(200).send({
        res: "KO",
        msg: error
      });             
    }
  });
```

Everyone can mint. I use Metamask to get address.

Anyone can help me??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is quite common as this is a small issue with carring the same connected provider to the approval instance,

here is the fix,

```
         let provider;
          await web3Modal
            .connect(web3Modal)
            .then((res) => {
              provider = res;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.error(err)
              
            });
```

the response provider is then used for connecting or for performing the actions of every transaction linked with the same account.

```
const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

will be the final solution,

```
Contract.setProvider(provider);
```

would be the solution for this issue.

Comment: At the end I moved my function call to frontend and this solved the issue.
Anyway I'll use your method next time
Thanks for your answer